# How to change the date of a docker container without using libfaketime?

Tags: database, docker, db2, containers

I am trying to launch a container at runtime with a different date :

`docker run -it db container /bash/bin date +%T -s "20190322 10:00:00"`

This doesn't changes also the date of the system.

Comment: I tried to do the same some time ago and couldn't find an alternative to libfaketime.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the date library is shared between the docker container and the system.